# Is there a way of attaching a document to a release as a requirement? Is there an extension that can be added?

Tags: azure-devops

Scenario 1
A pull request is created and one of the requirements is that a document has to be attached.

Scenario 2
A Release is created and one of the requirements is that a document has to be attached.

I've looked through Azure Devops settings for releases or pull requests.
Also I've look in the project settings.

Comment: Could you please describe your problem more clearly? What is the use of the document you mentioned? Regarding Scenario 1, is it one of the changed files in the pull request? Regarding Scenario 2, is it a file in the artifact source of the release pipeline?

Comment: No it is a separate document that is use in service now. It is not in the list of files in the pull request.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function currently. You can request a feature for Azure DevOps [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest) and share the link here. Other users may vote on it if they also need this function.